# Why does replacing a variable in a expression by variable with same name but different symbol name not work

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

How do I  replace a variable in a function with a new definition of 
the initial variable ?

```
import sympy as sy
g, a, x = sy.symbols("g a x")
g = 5*a*x
```

Entering g in the interpreter at this point prints:
 
5*a*x.

Now I would like to replace the printed a with an alpha. Why does 
the following not work?

```
a = sy.symbols("alpha")
g = g.subs(a,a)
```

I am well aware that i could use the following:

```
import sympy as sy
g, a, x = sy.symbols("g a x")
g = 5*a*x
alpha = sy.symbols("alpha")
g = g.subs(a,alpha)
```

But I would like to understand why the former approach is not working. Generally I am interested how the assigned name a= and the string in symbols("a") are connected. Must they be the same for sympy to work correctly ?

Comment: I don't know sympy, but this: `g = g.subs(a,a)` to me, says 'sub alpha with alpha".

Comment: Good point. Any idea how to substitute the initial a ?

Comment: again, I don't know sympy, but I suppose you should assign the result of `g.subs(a,a)` to another variable.

Comment: Or use `g.subs(sy.symbols('a'), alpha)`

Comment: That works with the order swapped, `g=g.subs(a, sy.symbols("alpha") )`. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g = g.subs(a, a)` can never do anything, as it's replacing a thing with itself.

To replace `a` with something else

```
g.subs(a, sy.symbols('alpha'))
```

should be used. The relevant topic in SymPy docs is [Assignment does not create a relation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#variables-assignment-does-not-create-a-relation-between-expressions). A simpler example:

```
a = sy.symbols('a')
b = a + 3      # b is now a+3 
a = 5          # b is still a+3 and it will not become 8
```

At the end of this code, the Python variable `a` has no relation to the SymPy symbol named "a". The variable is 5; the symbol is still `Symbol("a")` and will forever be, as SymPy expressions are immutable. Instead of `a = 5` one should have done `b.subs(a, 5)` to perform the substitution.

> I am interested how the assigned name a= and the string in symbols("a") are connected.

They are not connected at all. It's convenient to use Python variable `a` to point to a symbol named "a", that is the only reason people do that. Unfortunately the pattern then misleads them into thinking that if they put `a` = something new, that will have an effect on `Symbol("a")` -- it will not. The only effect is that Python variable now points to something else; the expressions containing `Symbol("a")` are unaffected.

Comment: How would you substitute `alpha` in g, after you did `g.subs(a, sy.symbols('alpha'))` ?<br>There is no reference to variable `alpha`, so it is not possible to call `g.subs(alpha, sy.symbols('something_else'))`.

Comment: You can refer to symbol "alpha" as `Symbol("alpha")`.